# Nothing shows up after setState filling by components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, spread-syntax

Client: React, mobx
Server: NodeJS, MongoDB

Short question:

I have an array of elements which fills inside of useEffect function, expected result: each element of array should be rendered, actual result: nothing happens. Render appears only after code changing in VSCode.

Tried: changing .map to .forEach, different variations of spread operator in setState(...[arr]) or even without spread operator, nothing changes.

Info:

Friends.jsx part, contains array state and everything that connected with it, also the fill-up function.

```
  const [requestsFrom, setRequestsFrom] = useState([]) //contains id's (strings) of users that will be found in MongoDB
  const [displayRequestsFrom, setDisplayRequestsFrom] = useState([]) //should be filled by elements according to requestsFrom, see below

  const getUsersToDisplayInFriendRequestsFrom = () => {
    const _arr = [...displayRequestsFrom]
    requestsFrom.map(async(f) => {
      if (requestsFrom.length === 0) {
        console.log(`empty`) //this part of code never executes
        return
      } else {
        const _candidate = await userPage.fetchUserDataLite(f)
        _arr.push( //template to render UserModels (below)
          {
            isRequest: true,
            link: '#',
            username: _candidate.login,
            userId: _candidate._id
          }
        )
        console.log(_arr)
      }
    })
    setDisplayRequestsFrom(_arr)
    // console.log(`displayRequestsFrom:`)
    console.log(displayRequestsFrom) //at first 0, turns into 3 in the second moment (whole component renders twice, yes)
  }
```

Render template function:

```
  const render = {
    requests: () => {
      return (
        displayRequestsFrom.map((friendCandidate) => {
          return (
            <FriendModel link={friendCandidate.link} username={friendCandidate.username} userId={friendCandidate.userId}/>
          )
        })
      )
    }
  }
```

useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`requestsFrom.length === ${requestsFrom.length}`)
    if (!requestsFrom.length === 0) {
      return 
    } else if (requestsFrom.length === 0) {
      setRequestsFrom(toJS(friend.requests.from))
      if (toJS(friend.requests.from).length === 0) {
        const _arr = [...requestsFrom]
        _arr.push('0')
        setRequestsFrom(_arr)
      }
    }
      if (displayRequestsFrom.length < 1 && requestsFrom.length > 0) {
         getUsersToDisplayInFriendRequestsFrom()
         //displayRequestsFrom and requestsFrom lengths should be same
      }
    
  },
   [requestsFrom]
  )
```

Part of jsx with rendering:

```
    <div className={styles.Friends}>
      <div className={styles['friends-container']}>
           {render.requests()}
      </div>
    </div>
```

UPD: my console.log outputs in the right order from beginning:

```
requestsFrom.length === 0
requestsFrom.length === 3
displayRequestsFrom === 0
displayRequestsFrom === 3
```

As we can see, nor requestsFrom, neither displayRequestsFrom are empty at the end of the component mounting and rendering, the only problem left I can't find out - why even with 3 templates in displayRequestsFrom component doesn't render them, but render if I press forceUpdate button (created it for debug purposes, here it is:)

```
  const [ignored, forceUpdate] = React.useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);

  <button onClick={forceUpdate}>force update</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRICIPAL ANSWER

The problem here is that you are executing fetch inside .map method.
This way, you are not waiting for the fetch to finish (see comments)

*Wrong Example (with clarification comments)*

```
  const getUsersToDisplayInFriendRequestsFrom =  () => {
    const _arr = [...displayRequestsFrom];
    // we are not awating requestsFrom.map() (and we can't as in this example, cause .map is not async and don't return a Promise)
    requestsFrom.map(async (f) => { 
        const _candidate = await userPage.fetchUserDataLite(f)
        // This is called after setting the state in the final line :( 
        _arr.push( 
          {
            isRequest: true,
            link: '#',
            username: _candidate.login,
            userId: _candidate._id
          }
        )
    } )
    setDisplayRequestsFrom(_arr) // This line is called before the first fetch resolves.  
   // The _arr var is still empty at the time of execution of the setter
 }
```

To solve, you need to await for each fetch before updating the state with the new array.

To do this, your entire function has to be async and you need to await inside a for loop.

*For example this code became*

```
  const getUsersToDisplayInFriendRequestsFrom =  async () => {  // Note the async keyword here
     const _arr = [...displayRequestsFrom]
     for (let f of requestsFrom) {
       const _candidate = await fetchUserData(f)
       _arr.push(
         {
           isRequest: true,
           link: '#',
           username: _candidate.login,
           userId: _candidate._id
         }
       )
     }
     setDisplayRequestsFrom(_arr)
 }
```

You can also execute every fetch in parallel like this

```
  const getUsersToDisplayInFriendRequestsFrom =  async () => {  // Note the async keyword here
     const _arr = [...displayRequestsFrom]
     await Promise.all(requestsFrom.map((f) => { 
       return fetchUserData(f).then(_candidate => {
          _arr.push(
            {
              isRequest: true,
              link: '#',
              username: _candidate.login,
              userId: _candidate._id
            }
          )
      });
     }));
     setDisplayRequestsFrom(_arr);
 }
```

---

### Other problems

#### Never Calling the Service

Seems you are mapping on an empty array where you are trying to call your service.

```
const getUsersToDisplayInFriendRequestsFrom = () => {
const _arr = [...displayRequestsFrom]
/* HERE */ requestsFrom.map(async(f) => {
  if (requestsFrom.length === 0) {
    return
```

If the array (requestsFrom) is empty ( as you initialized in the useState([]) ) the function you pass in the map method is never called.

Not sure what you are exactly trying to do, but this should be one of the problems...

---

#### Don't use state for rendered components

Also, you shoudn't use state to store rendered components

```
 _arr.push(
          <FriendModel key={_candidate.id} isRequest={true} link='#' username={_candidate.login} userId={_candidate._id}/>
        )
```

, instead you should map the data in the template and then render a component for each element in your data-array.

For example:

```
function MyComponent() {
   const [myData, setMyData] = useState([{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}])

   return (<>
        {
         myData.map(obj => <Friend friend={obj} />)
         }
   </>)
}
```

Not:

```
function MyComponent() {
   const [myDataDisplay, setMyDataDisplay] = useState([
         <Friend friend={{name: 'a'}} />, 
         <Friend friend={{name: 'b'}} />
   ])

   return <>{myDataDisplay}</>
}
```

---

#### Don't use `useEffect` to initialize your state

I'm wondering why you are setting the `requestsFrom` value inside the `useEffect`.

Why aren't you initializing the state of your `requestsFrom` inside the `useState()`?

*Something like*

```
const [requestsFrom, setRequestsFrom] = useState(toJS(friend.requests.from))
```

instead of checking the length inside the `useEffect` and fill it

*So that your useEffect can became something like this*

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (displayRequestsFrom.length < 1 && requestsFrom.length > 0) {
     getUsersToDisplayInFriendRequestsFrom()
  }
},
 [requestsFrom]
)
```

Comment: What I'm actually trying to achieve:
 1. Before page loads: data about the requests (user id's) fetching and storing in mobx
 2. After: map through id's to get actual users - this is happening here, everything written above is to render these users (by storing UserModels in state)

I set up a template and func that renders UserModel using template. Behavior still same

Thank you for advising not to store components in state, I did it. U'r right, problem: my component maps through empty array. I will figure out why it doesnt rerender when array is filled and will mark this as an anwser

Comment: Also, requests.length output is more than 0 after fetching

Comment: I console.logged if(requestsFrom.length === 0), it never executes, so seems this array isn't empty

Comment: Right now my console.logs in order from beginning after component mounts: requestsFrom = 0; requestsFrom = 3; displayRequestsFrom = 0; displayRequestsFrom = 3. So I see there's some problem with rerender, cause after changing and saving code in VSC and after recompiling dev-build page rerenders is I need. I created forceUpdate function and checked - after this everything renders as intended

Comment: If you could edit your snippets or make a https://stackblitz.com runnuble example of your updated code maybe i could help you better... It's difficult to get what you are exactly trying right now from this comments :)

Provide updated code (by editing your post) or a stackblitz runnable please :)

Comment: Updated question from beginning (not only after UPD section)

Comment: I can mark it right now, thank you very much, I feel I'm on right way to fix problems, but still re-render problem is not fixed yet, but your advises were very helpful even if they did not helped me with my main problem. Can I mark your answer right now, according to SO rules, and will this question be active after I'll mark your answer to get help?

Comment: Yes, anyone else can keep posting answer if they think is needed after you mark something as an answer.

Only when a question is "Closed" no one can post anymore.

And thanks for marking :)

Anyway i'm taking a look on your updated code 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245766/discussion-between-francesco-bellini-and-mortvicious).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your last section solved every problem I had! Fully workable code now.

Comment: I've done a final remix to make the answer more readable and priority-oriented!  :) I'm officially done!